# Python multiprocessing with Process : "could not create trigger pipe"

Tags: python, process, triggers, multiprocessing

I'm trying to multiprocess a code I've just written in Python using multiprocessing library.
Here is the part of the code I'm trying to multiprocess:

```
for b in (Bulle):
    p=[]
    for i in range(len(X)):
        print(i,"/",len(X))
        for j in range(len(Y)):
            for n in b.voisins:
                c_pos=[X[i][j],Y[i][j]]
                if __name__ == "__main__":
                    p.append(Process(target=fonction_courant2,args=(b,n,c_pos)))
    for i in (range(len(p))): p[i].start()
    for i in (range(len(p))): p[i].join()
```

Output:

```
NotifierThreadProc: could not create trigger pipe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "multi_t_bubbles.py", line 113, in <module>
    for i in (range(len(p))): p[i].start()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/multiprocessing/process.py", line 105, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/multiprocessing/context.py", line 212, in _Popen
    return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/multiprocessing/context.py", line 267, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/multiprocessing/popen_fork.py", line 21, in __init__
    self._launch(process_obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/multiprocessing/popen_fork.py", line 69, in _launch
   parent_r, child_w = os.pipe()
 OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files
```

I'm fairly new in multiprocessing (I took https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process as a base for this code) and I don't understand this output. It seems that the creation of Processes is ok, but not the start.

I would be really grateful if you have any suggestions!

Tom

Comment: what are the lengths of X and Y? it seems as if you exceed the maximum number of open files on your system (they are opened by the processes you spawn). It's in general not a good idea to create a lot more processes than you have processors. A `multiprocessing.Pool` is probably what you want to help you work through a lot of work with a pool of processes.

Comment: `OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files` explains it

Comment: Hi! Thank you for you answers! In fact, where I was surprised is that I'm working with a 8-logical cores processor (Intel Core i7), and when I put a counter, it seems that the process creation fail only after 2 processes created which much inferior than my processor number, so I thought I did something wrong in the way to create process... I think I will look for making a `multiprocessing.pool`. Thank you!